# Why dont i get the Controls in my youTube player

Tags: javascript, integration, youtube

I've made some integration with the youTube API, and embedded a player with swf object - But im not getting the controls like play, rewind, forward, fullscreen, volume and stuff in my player...

Look at the big player: www.tvskive.dk, there isn't any controls

Any idea to whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you using the "chromeless" youTube player instead of the regular embedded one?

> The chromeless player is, by definition, a YouTube video with no controls. This makes it easy to customize within Flash or HTML.

See [YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html)

Comment: Nope, if you look at the embed tag, the src is: 
http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer

Answer (score 0):

You're using the chromless player, to get the normal player you have to use the following embedSWF:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", 
                   "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

You still get all of the Javascript commands, you just have to change the embed to switch videos.
See here for more info: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted